# Detection of Anomalous Sequential User Behavior

Tags: anomaly-detection, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a dataset containing a set of normal user sessions. Each session contains a suite of ordered user requests on N system resources {R1, ..., RN}.

[image]

I want to design a continuous authentication algorithm, by confirming the user identity at each request command. More precisely, I don’t to let the user complete the whole session (all commands sequence) to authenticate him, but I want to do this at each resource requested command based on his previous normal sequences in the dataset.

How can I build a model over normal sequences to detect anomalous ones in Resource-by-Resource fashion ?

I found a lot of key concepts (Sequential Pattern Mining, Sequence Anomaly Detection, …), but I am completely confused about these concepts

I would like to know how to begin and which ML algorithm(s) I should use.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is commonly called discrete sequence anomaly detection.

One way to begin is to generate an anomaly score for the current item. If the anomaly score is above a threshold, label it as "anomalous".

An example of this approach is "[A Sequence Anomaly Detection Approach Based on Isolation Forest Algorithm for Time-Series](https://www.springerprofessional.de/en/a-sequence-anomaly-detection-approach-based-on-isolation-forest-/17113528)" by Weng and Liu.